# Any Audio Player Framework for Swift?

Tags: audio, swift2, xcode7, ios9.2

Is here any audio Library or Framework to use with Swift 2.x. I am looking for something which can handle the Live Stream Buffering or latency. I am using AVAudio Player for Live stream but it is not an excellent choice. I don't know the objective c , so its hard for me to get reference to those docs.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one of the best library which is purely written in swift.

[Jukebox](https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox)

However, you can still use `AVPLayer`. It's the one and the same thing.